Issue with Module Not Found Error in React Component (AWS Amplify/Graphql)
all npm install amplify went well before.
I have created an WebApp using Amplify in AWS.
Then I tried to connect Data modeling in Amplify studio to make a database for it.
screenshot
Error Messages:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './graphql/mutations' in
'path/to/my/project/src'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './graphql/queries' in
'path/to/my/project/src'

That amplify pull should have created the folder of graphql for me as that path is based on their recommendation.
Did i misplace the folder somewhere? Please advice me
I have try to find the path in my project but i can't find it.

I solved by the help of discord gentleman to use amplify codegen
